# iframe "YouTube search result" on Facebook app

Tags: html, iframe, youtube, facebook-iframe

I only know a little about coding, I recently want to set up an Iframe of YouTube results attach to a [Facebook app](https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/?fb_source=bookmark_apps&ref=bookmarks&count=0&fb_bmpos=3_0) (Thunderpenny Static HTML: iframe tabs)

Here is my code :

```
<html>
<body>
    <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/results?filters=week&search_query=funny+videos&lclk=week">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

If I load this on the Facebook app nothing happens.
I hope you get what I'm trying to picture out. Thank you!

Comment: or do you know any other way I can show this page on that Facebook App 
https://www.youtube.com/results?filters=week&amp;search_query=funny+video&amp;lclk=week

Answer (score 1):

I also wanted to add an Youtube or Google search results within an iframe in my personal project.

And I found that Google, Youtube blocked this option.. 
They set X-FRAME-OPTIONS to be "SAMEORIGIN" to prevent Clickjacking attacks

Here is a simple demo of how the clickjacking attack works.. and this is why Google and Youtube blocked the option to add those site in IFRAME
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W0fTFHCxXBY